# How do I include images in a Magento module?

Tags: magento

I want the images to be displayed on the webpage, but included in the Magento module.

1. Which folder do I put them in?
2. How do I reference to them? *(I'll need a variable for the module path.)*

The documentation, various external tutorials and a Google search provides no help.

All I see under `design/frontend/default/default` folder is `etc` `layout` `locale` `template` and nowhere to put images.

Do I put them in the `skin/frontend/default` folder? If so, where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your module applies to Magento 1.4+, your images belong under `./skin/frontend/base/default/images/`, ideally in a folder indicating your module's namespace and name, e.g. `namespace_module`. They can then be referenced in the following ways:

- A module CSS file at `base/default/css/namespace_module/file.css`: `url(../../images/namespace_module/image.jpg)`
- A template (or block): `$this->getSkinUrl('images/namespace_module/image.jpg')`
- Anywhere: `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/namespace_module/image.jpg');`

FYI, nothing under the `./app/` directory is accessed (should be accessed) directly by the browser.

Comment: When you say _module's namespace then name_, does that mean that I can have my `/desbest/showdown` folder inside the `skin/frontend/default` folder, and have `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl` point to that?

Comment: It is only a matter of preference. By convention, I'd say to put your folders inside each asset type folder (css, image, js). The `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl()` will always point to the configured theme, which will fallback to `base/default`.

Comment: I'm making a magento **module**, _not_ a theme. Because I'm using the default theme, it _always_ falls back to `base/default`. I want to include images within my module, so I need to know exactly how to do that.

Comment: It is useless to point my folders of assets to the specific theme, because the person using my modules might change the theme. That would render my module's assets _(img/css/js)_ as broken. I want to create asset folders for modules, and not for a theme.

Comment: ...which is what I've explained here. Magento theme assets fall back to the base/default theme, under which you should place your assets. See Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package for the skinny.

Comment: But I thought it was a bad practise to upload things into the `base/` folder. Shouldn't it go in the `core` folder?

Comment: Close! You have it backwards. frontend/base/default under app and skin were introduced in 1.4 to provide module developers with a configuration-independent location for asset placement/resolution.

Comment: That's what I meant. So is it `frontend/base/default`? instead of `frontend/default/default`?

Comment: There is no frontend/core/default oob.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13283/discussion-between-benmarks-and-desbest)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to shipping your image as part of your extension, is to host it on your webserver (*or someone else's*) and then include it by URL in your extension.

If that's the case, and you want the image to show up on your basic admin pages, then you just put html directly into your system.xml (escape it first). Otherwise, if you're including it in your templates, just put it in with an `img` html tag.

Couple of benefits to this approach:

1) You can look at your Apache logs each month and see how many times your image got viewed (i.e how many people are installing your extension) and also, from the referer HTTP header, you can see which sites are using it too.

2) When your wildly successful internet company gets acquired, you can easily swap in a different logo.jpg on your webserver, without having to roll out a new version of your extension.

So it's not the *right way*, but it's a simple way with a couple of benefits.