# Displaying images in magento extension backend

Tags: magento

I am developing an extension and want to display images on extension backend page. I have stored images in 'images' folder in my extension.
I am trying to show images using `<img>` tag. I have provided image url in "src" attribute, but its not showing image at the backend page.
In `system.xml`, I am using following code:-

```
<myOption translate="label">
    <label>My Label</label>
    <frontend_type>radios</frontend_type>
    <source_model>mymodule/source_buttons</source_model>
    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</myOption>
```

Code in `Model\Source\Buttons.php` file:-

```
 <?php
 class mycompany_mymodule_Model_Source_Buttons
 {
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $result = array();
        $result[] = array('value' => '32', 'label'=>'<img src="'.Mage::getModuleDir('', 'mycompany_mymodule').DS.'Skin'.DS.'Images'.DS.'img32.png" />');
        $result[] = array('value' => '16', 'label'=>'<img src="'.Mage::getModuleDir('', 'mycompany_mymodule').DS.'Skin'.DS.'Images'.DS.'img16.png" />');

        return $result;  
    }   
 }
```

On the extension backend page, its showing:-

```
<img src="C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\community\mycompany\mymodule\Skin\Images\img32.png">
```

But the `src` attribute value is linking to :-

```
http://mydomain/magento/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/mymodule_options/key/b834efa05ef37070c94d28c6b44e4bf0/C:/wamp/www/magento/app/code/community/mycompany/mymodule/Skin/Images/img32.png
```

Please help...

Comment: Could you show a bit of your php code and the html output it gives ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have done this first time. Never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
echo $this->getSkinUrl();
```

you can get a path to your images.

Comment: did you named same name skin for backend and frontend?

Comment: Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('path/images.jpg',array('_area'=>'frontend')) try to set _area to backend

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also got some idea from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284303/how-do-i-include-images-in-a-magento-module)